# BioPython ValueError: alphabet is None; cannot interpret sequence

Tags: biopython

So I'm getting this error message when trying to align two SeqRecord objects.
Why is this error happening?
Here is the code (reference_genome is defined earlier in the code)

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio import Align
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord

d122_fragment1 = SeqRecord(Seq('CAGTGGAAATGAAAGTGATGGGGACACAAATGAATTGCTCGCACTTATGGAAATGGGGAACTTTGATCCTTGGATTGGTGATAATTTGTAGTGCCTCAAACAACTTGTGGGTTACAGTTTATTATGGGGTTCCTGTGTGGAGAGATGCAGATACCACCCTCTTTTGTGCATCAGATGCTAAAGCACATAAGACAGAAGTGCATAATGTCTGGGCTACACATGCCTGTGTACCCACAGACCCCAACCCACAAGAAATACACCTGGGAAATGTAACAGAAGATTTTAACATGTG'), id='p122_1', annotations={"molecule_type": "DNA"})
Seq_ref_genome = SeqRecord(Seq(reference_genome), id = 'ref', annotations={"molecule_type": "DNA"})

aligner = Align.PairwiseAligner()
alignments = aligner.align(Seq_ref_genome, d122_fragment1)
alignment = alignments[0]
print(alignment)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with Seq objects, not records. For records alignment you can use pairwise2 module.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio import Align
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord

d122_fragment1 = SeqRecord(Seq('CAGTGGAAATGAAAGTGATGGGGACACAAATGAATTGCTCGCACTTATGGAAATGGGGAACTTTGATCCTTGGATTGGTGATAATTTGTAGTGCCTCAAACAACTTGTGGGTTACAGTTTATTATGGGGTTCCTGTGTGGAGAGATGCAGATACCACCCTCTTTTGTGCATCAGATGCTAAAGCACATAAGACAGAAGTGCATAATGTCTGGGCTACACATGCCTGTGTACCCACAGACCCCAACCCACAAGAAATACACCTGGGAAATGTAACAGAAGATTTTAACATGTG'), id='p122_1', annotations={"molecule_type": "DNA"})
Seq_ref_genome = SeqRecord(Seq(reference_genome), id = 'ref', annotations={"molecule_type": "DNA"})

aligner = Align.PairwiseAligner()
alignments = aligner.align(Seq_ref_genome.seq, d122_fragment1.seq)
alignment = alignments[0]
print(alignment)
```